# powershell : using -Depth switch with Get-ChildItem and -Include

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble using Depth switch with Get-ChildItem
I would have thought that Depth 0 means only top level current directory

```
$doc_path = "\\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\"
$doc_fichier = "000180002*.tif"

$children = Get-ChildItem $doc_path -Depth 0 -Include $doc_fichier

foreach ($child in $children) {
    
    $child_path =  Split-Path -Path $child
    $child_fichier = Split-Path -Path $child -Leaf -Resolve 
    $child
    $child_fichier  
}
```

However script is pulling out these files:

```
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\000180002A.TIF
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\000180002B.TIF
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\000180002C.TIF
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\backup\000180002A.TIF
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\backup\000180002B.TIF
 \\EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\backup\000180002C.TIF
```

I am only interested in those in \EURODEV44\Archivage$\Archivage\2002\03\14\